# Optimizing a Möbius transformation for more than three points?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Assume that I have a set of $N$ complex numbers $\{z_1,...,z_N\}$ with corresponding images $\{w_1,...,w_N\}$. A [Möbius transformation can be defined by specifying three points and their images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). If $N>3$, no exact mapping for all points will exist in the general case. It is my goal to find one (or, in case of an underdetermined system, several) Möbius transformations which minimize the mismatch between the Möbius transformation

$$M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

and the target images $\{w_1,...,w_N\}$ in terms of (for example) least-squares:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}|M(z_n)-w_n|^2$$

This is a problem which can probably be solved iteratively, but what is the most elegant way of finding a solution to this problem?

*Note: a very similar question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380242/optimization-of-m%C3%B6bius-transformation), but unfortunately it wasn't answered back then.*

Comment: I suggest you switch to the squares of distances on the Riemann sphere. You will need to learn a little, I guess. It is just the complex plane with an added point at infinity. In particular, it is the standard unit sphere in R^3 under stereographic projection.

Comment: Oops, yes, that was also part of the original question. I have replaced the parantheses with the norm. Thanks!

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to your problem? I am having the same problem right now and could not really find anything useful. I tried using Nonlinear Least Squares optimization, but it seems this function is really sensitive to noisy data and I keep ending up in local minima that are not even close to fit my images.